# Script to execute a series of links

Tags: python, selenium

Hope you will be able to assist me!

I would like to write a script that would execute a series of links for me in the browser.

The script should go similar to this

```
var IDs
IDs = (1, 3, 7, 234, 123, 654, 265, 294, 632)
Link = www.link.com/user{IDs}

Loop {
if did not execute all the IDs from the list yet take the first one and add it to the {IDs} part of the link
}
Result:
Browser goes to www.link.com/user1
Browser goes to www.link.com/user3
Browser goes to www.link.com/user7
Browser goes to www.link.com/user234
and so on...
```

Pardon the human language in the code block, please.

I am familiar with Python and Selenium but I was wondering if you would have any suggestions of the easiest way to do this?

Comment: can you post the code that u've so far

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
IDs = [1, 3, 7, 234, 123, 654, 265, 294, 632]

for i in IDs:
    row = f'www.link.com/user{i}'
    #driver.get(row)
    print(row)
```

Prints, for example purposes:

```
www.link.com/user1
www.link.com/user3
www.link.com/user7
www.link.com/user234
www.link.com/user123
www.link.com/user654
www.link.com/user265
www.link.com/user294
www.link.com/user632
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually we don't accommodate requests to essentially write a script from scratch, but this is so easy I can present the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
IDs = (1, 3, 7, 234, 123, 654, 265, 294, 632)
for ID in IDs:
    link = f"www.link.com/user{ID}"
    driver.get(link)
```

Or if you want to initialize a new driver for each link, so that each opens in a new window, you can move the definition into the loop:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
IDs = (1, 3, 7, 234, 123, 654, 265, 294, 632)
for ID in IDs:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
    driver.get(f"https://www.link.com/user{ID}")
```